# How to use System::Threading::Interlocked::Increment on a static variable from C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to keep a static counter in a garbage collected class and increment it using Interlocked::Increment.  What's the C++/CLI syntax to do this?

I've been trying variations on the following, but no luck so far:

```
ref class Foo
{
   static __int64 _counter;

   __int64 Next()
   {
      return System::Threading::Interlocked::Increment( &_counter );
   }

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a(VS.80).aspx) to your `_int64` value, using the % tracking reference notation:

```
ref class Bar
{
    static __int64 _counter;

    __int64 Next()
    {
        __int64 %trackRefCounter = _counter;
        return System::Threading::Interlocked::Increment(trackRefCounter);
    }
};
```

Comment: The compiler will bind the formal parameter (which is a tracking reference) to the actual parameter, no need to jump through hoops.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the address-of operator:

```
return System::Threading::Interlocked::Increment( _counter );
```

In C++/CLI, like C++, there is no special notation for passing by reference.

or you could use the native function, [`InterlockedIncrement64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`#include <windows.h>`)

```
return ::InterlockedIncrement64(&_counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use the **native functions/macros** (i.e. `InterlockedExchangePointer`, etc... plus a lot of cool ones I didn't know about such as `InterlockedXor64`) is severely hampered by the fact that doing so can cause an intrinsic (at least with the default compiler settings) to be dropped into your managed `C++/CLI` function. When this happens, your whole function will be compiled as native.

And the managed versions of `Interlocked::*` are also nice because you don't have to `pin_ptr` if the target is in a GC object. However, as noted on this page, it can be a real pain to find the right incantations for getting it to work, especially when you want to swap, (i.e) native pointers themselves. Here's how:

```
int i1 = 1, i2 = 2;

int *pi1 = &i1, *pi2 = &i2, *pi3;

pi3 = (int*)Interlocked::Exchange((IntPtr%)pi1, IntPtr(pi2)).ToPointer();
```

I verified that this does work properly, despite the suspiciously unnerving lack of address-taking (`&`) on the `pi1` pointer. But it makes sense, when you think about it because if the target is moving about in a GC host, you wouldn't want to do the usual `**` thing by grabbing the `&` (native) address of the pointer itself.